# negative margin-bottom is not applied to child div to cancel the margin from parent div

Tags: html, css, margin

```css
#parent {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#child1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#child2 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
      <div id="child2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the margin-bottom on child2 is not working even though the property is being applied on the div. Someone please help me.

I need to somehow cancel the margin added by parent by adding negative margin-bottom to child2

Please use https://jsfiddle.net/nishantmudgal/wy2b7eg9/1/ to try it as somehow the issue is not reproduced on above snippets.

Comment: Post image of the output you want.

Comment: @Newbee the output is simple that the bottom margin should not be present but somehow its working as expected through above snippets but i have added a link for jsfiddle where the issue is present.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do here. What's the actual problem?

Comment: i'm just trying to remove the margin added by parent through child2 by giving a negative margin to it. magin-top is working as expected but margin-bottom is not working.

Comment: define *not working*. Your code is doing what is supposed to do so it's working fine.

Comment: parent's bottom margin is still there but it should not be there, as i have added negative margin-bottom to child2

Answer (score 0):

Dude, it works. If you add a sibling to your `#parent`, you'll see this:

```css
#parent {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#child1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#child2 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
}

#sibling {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">
    <div id="child2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="sibling"></div>
```

P.S. Use classes instead of id

Answer (score -1):

Your `#child2` margin collapses with your `parent` margin. And as your `parent` margin is the biggest of the 2, `#child2's margin is ignored.

Margin collapses are a bit tricky, you can find a detailed explanation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_box_model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

My guess is that the collapse  happens because you don't have content between your parents and your descendants, i.e. you can probably stop it by adding a padding, border etc. to `child1` or `child2` for instance.

That being said, "cancelling" a margin with anothe rmargin sounds like a hack, and it will for sure make your code less readable. I don't know your specific use case, but I'd consider alternatives...

Comment: Yes. Margin collapses are tricky. If you read the bit at your link that starts "When negative margins are involved..." you'll note that #child2's negative margin is not ignored. It in fact compensates for the parent's positive margin exactly as the OP desires.

Comment: oops. Thanks for correcting me. Then I don't understand the OP's issue.

Comment: Yes somehow its working here as expected but I was using jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nishantmudgal/wy2b7eg9/1/ and here the issue is present(same as my codebase).